# Duplicate tags related to "assembly"

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I found some duplicate tags.

## .NET assemblies

Merge [assemblies](/questions/tagged/assemblies) into [.net-assembly](/questions/tagged/.net-assembly).

## Disassembly

- [disassembly](/questions/tagged/disassembly)
- [disassembling](/questions/tagged/disassembling)
- Related: [disassembler](/questions/tagged/disassembler). For comparison, [assembler](/questions/tagged/assembler) is a synonym of [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep [diassembler](/questions/tagged/diassembler) and [disassembling](/questions/tagged/disassembling) as the separate tags that they are - one is a type of tool, the other is the action of using that tool or interpreting its output.

Students and those new to asm (and possibly some real old-timers) will frequently use [assembler](/questions/tagged/assembler) as a synonym for [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly), but this will never be the case for the disassembly/disassembling tags.